# How to setup an existing Gradle project on STS with springframework libraries?

Tags: gradle, compiler-errors, spring-tool-suite, spring-framework-beans, sts

I have downloaded a gradle spring boot project from GitHub. I'm using STS (Spring Tool Suite). I have downloaded the Gradle plugin from marketplace. and I have tried options such as manually adding the eclipse and eclipse-wtp plugins and the classpath like below to the build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'eclipse-wtp'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.13'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
    id "org.unbroken-dome.test-sets" version "4.0.0"
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
      file {
            whenMerged {
                def source = entries.find { it.path == 'src/main/java' }
                source.entryAttributes['ignore_optional_problems'] = 'true'
            }
    }
}
```

}

However, I cannot build the project and I get error messages on imports related to annotations such as below:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
```

Can you please guide me in how to build this gradle project with STS and resolve the errors?

p.s. I have downloaded latest gradle too. if I navigate to the project folder on CMD and run it with "gradle bootRun", tomcat comes up properly. but I don't know how to set it up on STS!

Answer (score 1):

If you download and use the latest Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution, there is usually nothing you need to add in order to use Gradle, the Buildship tooling comes pre-installed.

With that, you can select "Import -> Gradle / Existing Gradle Project", select your Gradle project, and go from there.

If your Gradle build file works in general, this should work just fine in the IDE, including resolving all the necessary dependencies that you have defined in your build file. So if your Gradle build runs fine from the command line, the import into the IDE should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Martin Lippert's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255234/4184811) helped me with the Quickstart Spring Boot sample project named "[demo](https://spring.io/quickstart)". To be more specific, in Spring Tool Suite 4:
`File -> Import -> Gradle -> Existing Gradle Project`
After clicking "Next", set Project root directory to `<workspace-spring-tool-suite-4>/demo` Then click "Finish". Then in "Gradle Tasks" pane, `demo -> application -> bootRun` Click on `bootRun` to execute the project. STS4 brought me to the "Gradle Executions" pane. Observe the "Console" pane. (Replace "`demo`" with your project name.)